# Apache server correctly showing site on www.domainname.com but not on domainname.com despite using ServerAlias

Tags: apache, unix, virtualhost

I am trying to get my site up and running on DigitalOcean. I have installed everything and I can get the site to work at www.domainname.com however when I navigate to domaminname.com (without the www. prefix) I get the default page:

> It works!
>
> This is the default web page for this server.
>
> The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

What makes this strange (to me at least, I'm not very experienced with devops) is that my virtualhost file includes a server alias which I believe should take this into account. My domainname.com.conf file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName domainname.com
    ServerAlias *.domainname.com domainname.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@domainname.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domainname.com/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried with switching domainname.com with www.domainname.com as the servername and updating the serveralias accordingly but got the same issue. Any ideas about what I should do would be much appreciated.

Comment: do a DNS lookup for domainname.com and www.domainname.com and check whether they point to the same ip address

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just did checked and they both have the same ip.

Comment: Is this the entire virtual host config? Are there any other config settings for your apache?